Using SEMANTICSIMILARITYTABLE with a table?
If I do understand it right, then I can use SQL Server SEMANTICSIMILARITYTABLE to compare documents. But is it possible a query or a statement with documents and get a similarity score? If I do understand it right, then I can only compare documents that are inside the table dbo.Documents.
declare @ID int
declare @query_statement nvarchar(max) = 'text i want to compare with docs'

select  top 1
        @ID = ID
from    dbo.Documents with (nolock)

select  *
from    SEMANTICSIMILARITYTABLE
        (
            dbo.Documents,
            Body,
            @ID
        )

